# Issues with Ubuntu 18.04 video

Tags: 18.04, gui, desktop-environments, nvidia-geforce

Laptop has NVIDIA 1050ti video card, can’t to get it to load GUI across all screens. I’ve installed standard drivers using ‘ubuntu-drivers autoinstall’  I’ve ripped those out and installed the ‘beta’ drivers by adding the repo. I have finally removed and purged all drivers installed using apt removed and purged X11 and GNOME.  Installed X11 using and installed GUI using taskel. Booted to only one monitor again, installed the drivers from NVIDIAs site directly. In this iteration I get the GUI on the external screen and the native screen show terminal. I also added DisplayLink driver and can add a third monitor with a USB2 to VGA adapter but display 0 the laptop display still shows text no GUI. Not sure which logs to look at to try and diagnose what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried booting with the nomodeset kernel parameter?

You can head to this [Link](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

I had the “nomodset” kernel parameter it was one of the steps I added when removing X11. 
Since I had the vendor official drivers I reverted to noveau:

CTRL+ALT+f2
sh Nvidia.x.run -- uninstall

Restored my previous grub with out the nomodset entry (always backup Config files).

sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo reboot
That fixed it. Tried Ubuntu driver for NVIDIA still a problem now hdmi fails. Think I’m sticking with noveau.

Update:
So it seems running ‘Gnome Xorg’ option uses all 3 screens with NVIDIA drivers. Wow what an unstable driver set. I’m just persistent but I can see why Linux is not making it to the desktop.